# Can diskutil encrypt already existing primary boot partition on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, encryption, filevault

For example [this blog entry](http://www.nrtm.de/index.php/2011/07/04/live-encryption-of-non-bootable-partitions-with-os-x-10-7-lion/) mentions that an existing partition with `/Users` can be encrypted, but it also says "secondary driver". Same remark has been mentioned in a few other blog posts I found via google.

So the question is: I have a single volume in my MBP, where the OS itself is installed, and it contains all the userdata too.

Can it be encrypted via `diskutil` without data loss?

Rebooting is not an issue, just need automate the steps involved.

Comment: Okay, I've researched a bit and it *seems* you can only use File Vault 2 encryption for boot volumes, whereas `diskutil` encryption works for non-boot partitions only.

Answer (score 1):

`man diskutil` says:

> The volume must be resizable (the above types are) and also mounted.
>   Conversion is done live and in-place; targeting the boot volume is
>   supported; as much of the conversion as possible is done before an
>   eject or reboot is necessary.

So apparently answer to my question is "yes".

<sub>I'll keep the question open though if there are other comments incoming.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

So you may have a suitable answer to your question, but if you're still looking at the automation behind directly addressing your need, and if this is for a business, may I suggest http://code.google.com/p/cauliflowervest/ (CV for short,) an anagram for 'FileVault Escrow'. It uses googleApps account auth to secure individual recovery keys behind an organization, so that appropriate access can be granted.

Alternatives to that solution, to decouple it from google's endpoint, are in use inside certain organizations who have not open-sourced their solution to date. I described using the central tool to CV in a [standalone mode](http://www.aru-b.com/post/18185706679/standalone-cauliflower-complex), which can be driven by solutions like Puppet or Casper with the end state being logging the recovery key into a secured database.
Hope that isn't too far from the spirit of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is about diskutil, but people will get here looking for Disk Utility app solutions as I also couldn't find an encryption option for existing partitions.

You can **right-click on the mounted partition in Finder** and **select "encrypt"** to retroactively encrypt a partition that has been created unencryptedly without the need to delete the partition.

As for the automated portion, AppleScript may be an option to look into.

Answer (score -2):

No, their bootloader is about DRM, not about customer-friendly features. You can still have fully truecrypt-ed windows around.

Comment: What does that have to do with the boot loader? Lion supports volume-based encryption of any HFS+ volume, only the Recovery Partition and FAT, NTFS, etc. are not encryped. And using TrueCrypt on Windows is not even in the question here, why do you mention that?

Comment: Because MAC EFI bootloader does not boot from encrypted partition even it is theoretically possible to boot fully encrypted windows on the same system at the same time.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that it won't boot? Will the command just fail, or will the Mac not show any boot volume?

Comment: Sadly diskutil wil spit useless errors and get nowhere.

Comment: I was able to run "diskutil cs convert disk0s2 -passphrase XXX" on the volume Lion was installed, no errors and during the boot, i was presented a prompt asking for harddisk password so basicly everything what ZaB has said so far contradicts my findings.

Comment: @rasjani I wouldn't have expected anything less from this user given the "quality" of previous answers.

Comment: @ZaB: Since when are errors useless?